# Any plug-in that allows layer editing in the MirrorMap window?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

QGIS 'Dockable MirrorMap' I am using a plugin. This plugin is able to add one or more extra panels in the main window with additional map canvases.

The 'Dockable MirrorMap' plug-in simply has the ability to synchronize its location in the expanded window, is there a plug-in that allows layer editing in the expanded window?

Answer (score 3):

Yes plugins can do that. After the installation of a plugin from the repository they get added up in the GUI . For removing them from the panels you can right click and deselect or select tools whichever you want to see.

Comment: I guess, the asker doesn't ask how to open plugin's panel.